# Looking for a way to have dynamic recursive query go through a list of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database which has a set of tables which are linked through a relations table.

- It has an unknown number of levels of hierarchy
- It has an unknown number of records per level

The structure looks a bit like this:

```
TABLE1:          RELATIONS
ID         <-->  PARENT_ID    
TABLENAME  <-->  PARENT_TABLE      TABLE2         RELATIONS
                 CHILD_ID     <--> ID        <--> PARENT_ID  
                 CHILD_TABLE  <--> TABLENAME <--> PARENT_TABLE      TABLE3
                                                  PARENT_ID    <--> ID        ...
                                                  CHILD_TABLE  <--> TABLENAME ...
```

etc. etc.

I'm not a SQL expert and wonder how to approach this.

I think that for now I would like to just UNION the data and see how it would look like.

I would really appreciate your advice on how to address this.

Comment: What's are primary keys of each table? It's unclear from the example.

Comment: The primary key is ID in the tables but in the relations table the unique combination is a combination of all 4 columns.

Comment: That's not 3NF. You should clean up your database model. In the relations table the primary key should only include the pair of IDs, and exclude the table names.

Comment: I would agree with that if the data that was the source for the database content, is not random and you know what the next table or column would be.
The database has 50 tables and to verify 50 tables if any of them has a child of the parent table is a huge pain. That is why the person who worked initially on the issue came up with this approach. There are probably way better methods but for now I don't know of any that works for data that can change in format.

Comment: You explained well your structure   with a simple example but...  what are you trying to achieve: show relations, query tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to access any of the columns from the unspecified tables? If not you can change your image from this

```
TABLE1:          RELATIONS
ID         <-->  PARENT_ID    
TABLENAME  <-->  PARENT_TABLE      TABLE2         RELATIONS
                 CHILD_ID     <--> ID        <--> PARENT_ID  
                 CHILD_TABLE  <--> TABLENAME <--> PARENT_TABLE      TABLE3
                                                  PARENT_ID    <--> ID        ...
                                                  CHILD_TABLE  <--> TABLENAME ...
```

to this:

```
RELATIONS
PARENT_ID    
PARENT_TABLE      RELATIONS
CHILD_ID     <--> PARENT_ID  
CHILD_TABLE  <--> PARENT_TABLE      RELATIONS
                  PARENT_ID    <--> PARENT_ID
                  CHILD_TABLE  <--> PARENT_TABLE
                                    ...
                                    ...
```

In which case you can use a recursive Common Table Expression:

```
WITH R AS (
  //Anchor Query
  SELECT 1 LEVEL
       , A.PARENT_ID ROOT_ID, A.PARENT_TABLE ROOT_TABLE
       , A.PARENT_ID, A.PARENT_TABLE, A.CHILD_ID, A.CHILD_TABLE
    FROM RELATIONS A
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RELATIONS R        // Start with parents
                      WHERE R.CHILD_ID = A.PARENT_ID  // that aren't children
                        AND R.CHILD_TABLE = A.PARENT_TABLE)
  UNION ALL
  //Recursive Part
  SELECT R.LEVEL+1
       , R.ROOT_ID, R.ROOT_TABLE
       , A.PARENT_ID, A.PARENT_TABLE, A.CHILD_ID, A.CHILD_TABLE
    FROM R
    JOIN RELATIONS A
      ON A.PARENT_ID = R.CHILD_ID
     AND A.PARENT_TABLE = R.CHILD_TABLE
)
SELECT * FROM R
```

This will iterate through all related records.  Once you have the above query, if you need additional columns from the unspecified tables, you can simply left join to them as needed:

```
...
SELECT LEVEL, ROOT_ID, ROOT_TABLE
     , PARENT_ID, PARENT_TABLE, CHILD_ID, CHILD_TABLE
     , PT1.COL1, PT1.COL2, ...
     , CT1.COL1, CT1.COL2, ...
     , PTn.COL1, PTn.COL2, ...
     , CTn.COL1, CTn.COL2, ...
  FROM R
  LEFT JOIN TABLE1 PT1
    ON PT1.ID = R.PARENT_ID
   AND R.PARENT_TABLE = 'TABLE1' // OR PT1.TABLENAME = R.PARENT_TABLE
  LEFT JOIN TABLE1 CT1
    ON CT1.ID = R.CHILD_ID
   AND R.CHILD_TABLE = 'TABLE1' // OR CT1.TABLENAME = R.CHILD_TABLE
  LEFT JOIN TABLEn PTn
    ON PT1.ID = R.PARENT_ID
   AND R.PARENT_TABLE = 'TABLEn' // OR PT1.TABLENAME = R.PARENT_TABLE
  LEFT JOIN TABLEn CTn
    ON CT1.ID = R.CHILD_ID
   AND R.CHILD_TABLE = 'TABLEn' // OR CT1.TABLENAME = R.CHILD_TABLE
...
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems to help me forward

Answer (score 0):

To "walk" a hierarchy (or any kind of graph) you can use a Recursive CTE, as in:

```
with
x as (
  select id, tablename from table1 where id = 123 -- initial table
  union all
  select
  from relations r
  join x on r.parent_id = x.id
  join table1 t1 on t1.id = r.child_id
)
select * from x;
```

This query will start from one table and get all children, granchildren, etc., not just in two levels, but in all levels.

You can take it as a starting point to do whatever you want with it.